# AEM dialog submit event handler execute for a specific dialog

Tags: aem

I am trying to implement dialog submit event listener for a cq:dialog touchui.

JS dialog submit event listener getting executed for all dialog submits.
I am trying to see if I can bind event listener to a specific dialog - in a way

```
$(document).on("click", "**customCSSClass**.cq-dialog-submit", function(e) {
    //event handler for submit
});
```

AEM 6.3 sp2 is the version. Purpose is to to show hide some dialog fields based on drop down selection and validate value entered in dialog fields. Could someone tell me the attribute /property that I need to add to have a class name ? A small example code would help.

any help?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: You can add a specific class on the dialog itself. What version of AEM is this? also if you could elaborate on the purpose, maybe I could provide a better way to handle it via AEM/Coral Js APIs instead of attaching a click handler.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks for your reply. AEM 6.3 sp2 is the version. Purpose is to to show hide some dialog fields based on drop down selection and validate value entered in dialog fields.  Could you please tell me the attribute /property that I need to add to have a class name ?  A small example code would help.

Comment: Please adjust your question to reflect that purpose. Then I can add an example when I get a chance.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam updated the question. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://aemcases.blogspot.com/2018/05/touch-ui-hideshow-fields-in-dialog-in.html or this: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/ui-widgets/show-hide-widgets/index.html

Comment: and for field validation, this: https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2017/11/06/aem-touch-ui-dialog-validation-new-best-practice-use-foundation-validation/

Comment: Thanks @AhmedMusallam Show / Hide fields - Yes. Validations - No. I will check on validations. At the same time, I am curious to see in extjs world - there is "cls" property to define dialog class, is there an equivalent in touch ui. Thanks,

Comment: Ahh yes, for that, you should use `granite:class`, see documentation here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/docs/server/commonattrs.html